# can anbody provide me complete example of jamesarosen/ember-i18n when changing language from select menu?

Tags: ember.js

i have used `jamesarosen/ember-i18n` in my project.
but I don't know how to use into my code so that I can switch languages from the select menu.

for example

If I change the language from `English` to `hindi` from the select menu

```
{{ hello }} // output is hello in english
```

should change to

`{{ hello }} // output is नमस्कार in Hindi`

Would be great if someone can quote an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ember I18n lib currently has no way to real time change the language. Your only option is to reload the whole page. You can do this for example by adding a language to your URL like `http://localhost/en/app`, in your select menu you can then add `<a href="http://localhost/nl/app">Dutch</a>` as a link. This link will reload the app.

Somewhere in your app you then have to extract the language from your URL and set the right language for the Ember I18n lib. You can do this for example in a Ember Initializer (see [this](http://ember.zone/ember-application-initializers/)).

**Example**

Below follows an example of setting your translation with an Ember Initializer (using ember-cli).

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default {
    name: 'i18n',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        Ember.I18n.translations = {
            // your translations
        };
    }
};
```

I'm omitting the part of extracting the language from the URL as this might be very specific. You can start by extracting it from `location.pathname` which will give you the part of the url after the domain name (so the url without the `http://domainname.com` part).

When you define the language in the url, you probably want to change the root url of your ember application. For example if you want http://domainname.com/en/ to point to your ember application, you can for example create an initializer which sets the root url of the application:

```
export default {
    name: 'location',
    initialize: function(container,application) {
        application.Router.reopen({
            rootURL: 'en/' // the extracted language value
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: you actually can achieve what @tapan wants... a bit hacky but... you have to set Ember.I18n.translations as the new ones, then refresh the application route (`this.target.router.refresh()`) or using a fake route (going to e.g. /#i18n back and forth)

Comment: is this best practice ??

Comment: @andrusieczko You are right, you can do it this way, but I think it is always a good idea to define the language in your URL so users can go directly to the right language if they want.

Comment: @jcbvm can you give example of what you have written if possible?

Comment: @TapanBavaliya I've added an example to my answer